# <col> width returns 0 for IE and Chrome

Tags: jquery, col

I have a table with three columns. I am using  tag to specify the width of a column. Sample code:

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <colgroup style="background-color:#FF0000;">
  <col width="100px" id="id1"></col>
  <col width="80px" id="id2"></col><col id="id3"></col></colgroup>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>ISBN</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3476896</td>
    <td>My first HTML</td>
    <td>$53</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2489604</td>
    <td>My first CSS</td>
    <td>$47</td>
  </tr>
<tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is width of col ($("#id1").width()) returns 0 for IE and Chrome and it works fine in FF.
How do I get the actual width of col in chrome and IE?

Comment: I have verified your code in IE9, FF and Chrome. It is working fine. Here is the jsfiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/nXVYx/

Comment: It is not working with jquery-1.5.2.min.js. It is not working in fiddle if I change the jquery version to 1.5.2

Comment: I could not reproduce it. I have tested in FF 10 with JQuery 1.5.2, and it worked perfectly

Comment: It is working in FF and IE. The problem is with Chrome.

Comment: I am using jQuery 1.5.2. http://jsfiddle.net/YD5mM/1/  It is working with jquery 1.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the simple hack for older jQuery (col don't have width in Chrome, but it have first cell with width )

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <colgroup style="background-color:#FF0000;">
  <col width="100px"></col>
  <col width="80px"></col><col id="id3"></col></colgroup>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th id="id1">ISBN</th>
    <th id="id2">Title</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3476896</td>
    <td>My first HTML</td>
    <td>$53</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2489604</td>
    <td>My first CSS</td>
    <td>$47</td>
  </tr>
<tbody>
</table>
```

here - http://jsfiddle.net/YD5mM/2/

Comment: wont work the column who's width you want to calculate does not contain a cell in the tbody who's colspan is 1