# table-layout:fixed issue

Tags: css, tablelayout

I have a `table` with table-layout fixed. There are 2 columns in the table.

If I set the `colspan=2` for the first row then for the remaining rows it shows equal width. (It is not taking the width I specified.)

Fiddle attached [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kszaa/1/)

```
<table style='table-layout:fixed' border="1" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan='2'>10000</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="5%">1066fdg</th>
      <th width="95%">10</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Is there anyway to set the specified column width for the remaining rows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because fixed table layout is driven by first row OR column definition - try this

```
<table style='table-layout:fixed' border="1" width="100%">
     <col width="5%" />
     <col width="95%" />
     <thead>
          <tr>
               <th colspan='2'>10000</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <th>1066fdg</th>
               <th>10</th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: I need this column width to set it for the body td's. I posted one question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112849/col-width-returns-0-for-ie-and-chrome.

Comment: Brilliant. Sometimes you need fixed width tables *glares at IE*

Comment: Any way to do this in a purely CSS way? I have hundreds of pages within a website that require this update but I'm hoping to not have to go through an add `<col>` tags everywhere

Answer (score 0):

You have a width set on the `th` why not set a class in your style sheet to give the `th` and `tr` rows the widths you need?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<table style='table-layout:fixed' border="1" >
<col width="5%" />
<col width="95%" />
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan='2'>10000</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>1066fdg</th>
<th>10</th>
</tr>
    <tr><th>&nbsp</th><th>&nbsp</th></tr>
</thead>
</table>
```